# Mysql not starting due to innodb files

Tags: mysql, innodb

Mysql seems to be shutting down because of InnoDB files.
Why does that happen?
What should I do?

From the error.log file:

```
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: checksum mismatch in data file ./ibdata1
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
220122 15:10:03 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
220122 15:10:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
220122 15:10:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
220122 15:10:03 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
220122 15:10:03 [ERROR] Aborting

220122 15:10:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: What OS?  What version of MySQL?  Had MySQL run on the machine before, or is this a fresh install?  Had `ibdata1` been moved or modified?

Comment: It's running an old 14.04 version of Ubuntu. MySQL has always been running on the OS. As far as I know ibdata1 was not manipulated, it was just changed after running successive innodb_force_recovery. I started having errors on websites on the database connection "Error establishing database connection".

Comment: Now the websites are running but logs look awful. I have no clue about what to do.

Comment: "Error establishing database connection" - sounds like network or permission (`GRANT`) problems.

Comment: MySQL is running, now I have issues with innodb_force_recovery and logs. Thanks for your help!